Hint of solution without trigonometry

I was told that this question $x$ can be found without trigonometry. I tried to find all the angles but it seems there isn't enough information. Is it true that this question can solve without trigonometry?
I notice there are some isosceles triangle but still not related to x directly

I think you were told wrong. Unless I've made a mistake, $x$ does not appear to be a rational number of degrees.  It would be impossible to come up with an angle like that without trigonometry.

Do the red and the blue colours indicate anything, like equal lengths of sides?

@MathGuy For the red and blue, it follows from the given angle measures. Clearly not for the grays.

Yes. It can be solved without trigonometry. I label the points as follows. Additionally, $F$ is the intersection of $CE$ and the perpendicular bisector of line segment $BC$, $G$ is the intersection of $BD, CE$, and $I$ is the circumcenter of triangle $BEF$.

The angles of triangle $BEF$ are completely determined: $\angle EBF = 50^{\circ}$, $\angle BFE = 60^{\circ}$, $\angle BEF = 70^{\circ}$. Therefore we can calculate $\angle IBF = 90^{\circ} - \frac{1}{2}\angle BIF = 90^{\circ} - \angle BEF = 20^{\circ} = \angle DBF$, which implies $B, I, D$ are collinear.
On the other hand, $\angle DIE = 180^{\circ} - \angle BIE = 180^{\circ} - 2\angle BFE = 180^{\circ} - 120^{\circ} = 60^{\circ} = \angle DFE$. Therefore $DFIE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Moreover, $IE = IF$ so $DI$ is the angle bisector of $\angle EDF$, from which we can deduce that $\angle GDE = \angle GDF = 40^{\circ}$. Because $\angle DEG = \angle DGC - \angle GDE = 80^{\circ} - 40^{\circ} = 40^{\circ}$, we conclude that $x = 40^{\circ}$.
